# Cannot install geda-gschem in 13.10

Tags: software-installation

When I am trying to install the package **geda-gschem** from universe repo, I get the output:

```
sudo apt-get -f install geda-gschem
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 geda-gschem : Depends: libgeda (>= 43) but it is not installable
               Recommends: extra-xdg-menus but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The repo contains the package **libgeda43**, but it is not recognized as the required package **libgeda**. Does anybody know what can I do with that? Thanks.

Comment: Please, copy verbatim the error. Not paraphrasing.

Comment: I would like to, however, my command-line speaks Russian: sudo apt-get -f install geda-gschem
 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Некоторые пакеты невозможно установить. Возможно, вы просите невозможного,
или же используете нестабильную версию дистрибутива, где запрошенные вами
пакеты ещё не созданы или были удалены из Incoming.
Следующая информация, возможно, поможет вам:

Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:
 geda-gschem : Зависит: libgeda (>= 43) но он не может быть установлен

Comment: Use `LANG=C command`.

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install geda-gschem
...Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 geda-gschem : Depends: libgeda (>= 43) but it is not installable
               Recommends: extra-xdg-menus but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Please, edit your question, I can't make sense out your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package geda-gschem in Ubuntu 13.10 depends on libgeda42, not libgeda43. Try running these commands from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get -f install libgeda42  
sudo apt-get install geda-gschem
```

The -f flag in the first command will force Ubuntu to also install the libgeda-common1:1.8.1-3 package which is available in the Ubuntu Software Center in Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: I tried to install libgeda42. Apt-get says it cannot do that, because it depends on libgeda-common (< 1:1.8.1-3.1~), but 1:1.9.0+git20131202c-0ppa0~saucy will be installed.

Comment: @victor I can see from your comment that you have added a ppa to your Software Sources, and Ubuntu is trying to install the latest version of libgeda-common from the ppa that you added, instead of the default version of libgeda-common that is in the Ubuntu Software Center. I edited my answer following your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
sudo apt-get -f install geda-gschem
```

hope you can now get it installed.

Comment: With this command I got the same answer that the package depends on libgeda (>=43), which cannot be installed. Thanks anyway